# Why is the primary template selected over the specialization?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Q: Is this a strictly conforming C++17 program where the return value isn't (shouldn't be) implementation defined, and if so, what is the correct return value?

```cpp
template <char... Chars>
struct foo { inline static constexpr bool primary = true; };

template <bool Bool, char... Chars>
struct foo<Bool, Chars...> { inline static constexpr bool primary = false; }; // 5

int main() {
    return foo<true>::primary;       // gcc: 1, clang & icx: 0
}
```

My expectation was for the specialization to be selected (by all compilers) because `foo<true>` matches the specialization without converting the boolean `true` to `char` and also because the specialization is more constrained than the primary template (since it requires *at least* one parameter). Unfortunately, we use a gcc 7.3 -based toolchain where the above doesn't even compile, but the output from gcc 7.3 may provide a hint to someone answering this question:

```cpp
<source>:5:8: error: template argument '(char)Bool' involves template parameter(s)
 struct foo<Bool, Chars...> { inline static constexpr bool primary = false; };
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I therefore tried it out with gcc (trunk) in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4x4odWTo7) but to my surprise, even though gcc (trunk) compiles it, it selects the primary template.

If I change `true` to a `'a'`, clang & icx also selects the primary template, just like I want.

```cpp
template <char... Chars>
struct foo { inline static constexpr bool primary = true; };

template <bool Bool, char... Chars>
struct foo<Bool, Chars...> { inline static constexpr bool primary = false; };

int main() {
    return foo<'a'>::primary;       // gcc: 1, clang & icx: 1
}
```

I've tried to find the answer in [`[temp]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/#temp) in the final C++17 draft but I'm not able to piece it together.

---

Fwiw, even though the question was closed as a duplicate, I'll document my workaround here.

I made a `detail::foo_impl` which will always be used as a base class:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template <bool Bool, char... Chars>
struct foo_impl {
    static constexpr bool value = Bool;
};

}  // namespace detail
```

Then the primary became

```cpp
// The primary template which selects a value for the bool using
// some disjunction or conjunction. Here simplified to a fold:
template <char... Chars>
struct foo : detail::foo_impl<(... || (Chars == ' ')), Chars...> {};
```

and the specializations will be straight forward:

```cpp
// Specializations for `false` and `true`:
template <char... Chars>
struct foo<false, Chars...> : detail::foo_impl<false, Chars...> {};

template <char... Chars>
struct foo<true, Chars...> : detail::foo_impl<true, Chars...> {};
```

Now all compilers agree (even gcc 7.3) ...and also do what I wanted from the start.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6cdn7o6v3)

Comment: About the duplicate: In my code, it's not a matter of narrowing to match the specialization. In my case, it rather a "widening" of the `bool` to match the primary. Are those cases really the same?

Comment: It looks like that the accepted answer in the duplicate has a [link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1647) which is about the issue you described. However I believe that those two questions should not be considered to be duplicates, even if the answer to both would be about the same issue.

Comment: A template specialization, by definition, is some "subset" of the template. The template parameters are `char`s. A `bool` is not a `char`. This is not a specialization, but a different template that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the other one.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan Thanks! Yes, that link has an example that is _pretty_ close to my case. That specialization has `int, char...` while mine has `bool, char...`. In the link, the `1` would have to be narrowed to `char` while in my example, `true` would have to be widened to `char`. Perhaps not an important distinction.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Oh... perhaps there's something in that that can explain what behavior to expect? In the WG21 [link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1647) Karen shared they have `template<char...> struct char_values` vs. `template<int C1, char C3> struct char_values<C1, 12, C3>` and then it's a partial specialization - but if mine is not a specialization, perhaps I need to search for answers in some other section of the standard (or a duplicate Q&A here - but I couldn't find one)?